# Cosmos DB APIs performance comparison

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

I started to research Azure Cosmos DB and figured out that Cassandra API is not in GA yet. Although I'm generally interested in Cassandra API, I'm also trying to figure out how Cosmos DB works so I could possibly find a way how to use existing APIs for my needs.

What I understood from the official documentation:

- Cosmos DB stores data in the same way regardless of used API (MongoDB, Cassandra, etc.)
- Cosmos DB automatically indexes all the properties

Does it mean that I can use any other API (e.g. MongoDB, SQL, etc.) and expect similar performance as I would have if I could use Cassandra API?

Answer (score 1):

> > Cosmos DB stores data in the same way regardless of used API (MongoDB, Cassandra, etc.)

Cosmos DB stores data in the different ways when use different APIs.

> > Cosmos DB automatically indexes all the properties

By default, all Azure Cosmos DB data is indexed. More information for your reference: [How does Azure Cosmos DB index data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies)

> > Does it mean that I can use any other API (e.g. MongoDB, SQL, etc.) and expect similar performance as I would have if I could use Cassandra API?

Every API is suitable for the specify scenarios and has better performance in its suitable scene than others.

For example:

```
If we used to use MongoDB in the past, we can use Mongo API.

If we need to handle our data which is like model or to model both entities and relationships naturally, we can use graph api.

If we need to store data for apps which are written for Apache Cassandra, we can use Apache Cassandra API.
```

Comment: > Cosmos DB stores data in the different ways when use different APIs. - Do you have any documentation references regarding this?

Comment: @myarotskaya we can refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#how-does-azure-cosmos-db-support-various-data-models-such-as-keyvalue-columnar-document-and-graph

Comment: @myarotskaya As the official said, Azure Cosmos DB support various data models such as key/value, columnar, document and graph

Comment: -1 for the first point.  The storage engine is based on ARS (Atom Record Sequence) and no matter which API is chosen, the storage is the same.